# I want to display below array all model property values in a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to iterate this array and that all model property arrays should be stored in a single array.

```
var arr = [{car:"Honda", model:["a","b","c"]},
       {car:"Nissan", model:["a","b","c"]},
       {car:"Chevrolet", model:["a","b","c"]},
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatMap` with destructuring:

```js
var arr = [{car:"Honda", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Nissan", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Chevrolet", model:["a","b","c"]}];

const res = arr.flatMap(({ model }) => model);

console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var arr = [{car:"Honda", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Nissan", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Chevrolet", model:["a","b","c"]}];

var res = arr.map(function(item) {
  return item.model;
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  return acc.concat(curr);
});

console.log(res);
```

If you want to remove duplicates, use a `Set`:

```js
var arr = [{car:"Honda", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Nissan", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Chevrolet", model:["a","b","c"]}];

const res = [...new Set(arr.flatMap(({ model }) => model))];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: No problem @Ramya, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and return that `model` property of `arr` in `flatMap()`

```js
var arr = [{car:"Honda", model:["a","b","c"]},
       {car:"Nissan", model:["a","b","c"]},
       {car:"Chevrolet", model:["a","b","c"]},
      ]
      
const res = arr.flatMap(x => x.model);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing about [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is that it is super useful however does not have full support in IE.

What you need can also be easily done in one line with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and ES6 like this:

```js
var arr = [{car:"Honda", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Nissan", model:["a","b","c"]},{car:"Chevrolet", model:["a","b","c"]}]

let result = arr.reduce((r,{model}) => [...model, ...r], [])

console.log(result)
```